# Tab item width in Action Bar (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using 12 tabs in an Activity, in the Action Bar *(target is API 17, tested on Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2)*.

As expected, I get a horizontall scrolling list of tabs under my action bar. In the screenshot below, you can see that the last tab (B, on the right) is noticably smaller than the other tabs *(don't take the "E" tab into account, it can be scrolled as there are 4 more tabs on the left)*.

You can see from the blue glow that there is nothing more to scroll. I'm using the default Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionbar, without any custom view yet.

Why is this last tab smaller than the other ? And how can I make sure that it gets the same width as the others ?

[image: One tab is smaller than the others]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I came accross the same problem and the only work around I found was to disable the dividers between tabs. Looks like there is a bug in the native actionbar that does not take care of the dividers size when measuring tab bar container.

```
<style name="actionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
</style>
```

(Here I'm using actionbarsherlock but it is not the source of the problem you could extend your style from parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar")

And apply it in your theme:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/actionBarTabBarStyle</item>
```

If you absolutely need the actionBar divider, one simple solution may be to add it directly to the tab background (left or right)