# Last tab in action bar is cropped, goes off screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm making an Android app using tabs for navigation.
I have a problem with the rendering of the last tab in the action bar; it goes off screen and is cropped (this happens as soon as the number of tabs is too big too fit in the screeen width as far as I can tell).

[image]

I'm using the `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` navigation mode.

I haven't been able to find any questions with the same problem, any ideas on how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab item width in Action Bar (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137235/tab-item-width-in-action-bar-android)

Answer (score 0):

I have already answer a question like that one : [Tab item width in Action Bar (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439723/795245)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't been able to find it.

Comment: Do you think it's better if I delete my question, or mark your answer as accepted? I'd like to mark my own question as duplicate but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: I don't have enought reputation to flag it as duplicate either. So if you were unable to find the other post mentionning the answer maybe others will have the same problem, I would just mark that question as answered.

Comment: How is this an answer? You're basically taking out the line between the tabs. It would be dumb luck if it actually helps someone. I'm more amazed that you got it marked as the "answer" twice.