# Incorrect offset on action bar tabs in Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've added multiple tabs using ActionBarSherlock. On all devices it works correctly, except for one - a Motorola device running 2.2.3 when I have more tabs to display than can fit on the screen.

This is what the tabs look like on scrolling it to the most left hand side:

[image]

And here's what it looks like when scrolled to the right most side:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that causes the additional left padding and not enough padding on the right?

Has anyone seen this before? Is it a platform specific bug?

Comment: What Motorola device exactly is it? & can you post your tab styles?

Answer (score 0):

I have already answer a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137235/tab-item-width-in-action-bar-android/15439723#15439723). There is actually a bug in the native actionbar that does not take care of the dividers size when measuring tab bar container. So make sure to disable dividers in ActionBar, using showDivider none as explicated in my original answer

Comment: The particular issue I have is with a 2.3.6 device. I'm using ActionBarSherlock and not the native version. I've tried this but there was no change to the way it handled the tabs.

Comment: ABS automatically uses the native action bar if it can - are you sure this isn't happening?

Comment: It shouldn't be, because ABS use the native actionbar only for 4.0+ devices